# .flac file with google cloud speech API fails

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I've successfully run [this nodejs demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/recognize.js) from my local machine with the [supplied `.raw` file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/resources/audio.raw). Now I would like to use my own file, which started as a `.wav` file which I converted using the following sox command (as per step 3 of the [google speech troubleshoot page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/support)):

```
sox resources/my-audio.wav --channels=1 --bits=16 --rate=16000 --endian=little resources/my-audio.flac
```

However I am still getting an empty response from google (no transcript, no error) when I try with `my-audio.flac`. I can play the flac file just fine on my machine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out... turns out the sox command to convert the wav on the support page isn't quite right. Here is the command that worked for me:

```
sox resources/my-audio.wav \
--channels=1 \
--bits=16 \
--rate=16000 \
--encoding=signed-integer \
--endian=little resources/my-audio.raw
```

The two key differences with my original command were (1) add the `--encoding=signed-integer` (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383576/how-to-convert-16bit-wav-to-raw-audio)) and (2) use the `.raw` extension on the output filename.